# Remove child by its associated key

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have the following code so far, however, when the remove button is clicked the child is not removed. It seems like the click function is never triggered because I tried adding an alert statement and it doesn't work.

```
<table id="removeTable" class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Employee ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Remove</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="table_body"></tbody>
</table>

var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Employees");

rootRef.on('child_added', snap => {
  var id = snap.child("ID").val();
  var key = snap.key;
  var name = snap.child("Name").val();
  var email = snap.child("Email").val();
  var btn = "<button key='"+ key +"' class='removeEmployee mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent'>Remove</button>";

  $("#table_body").append("<tr id='"+key+"'><td>" + id + "</td><td>" + name + "</td> <td>" + email +
                          "</td><td><button>" + btn +"</button></td></tr>");

});

$("#removeEmployee").click(
  function(){
    alert();
  }
);

// now this click handler can be (should be) moved outside 'child_added' callback
  $(".removeEmployee").click(function(){ // note: using 'removeElement' as class, not as id
    alert("clicked!");
    var key = $(this).attr('key');
    var itemToRemove = rootRef.child(key);
    itemToRemove.remove()
   .then(function() { // removed from Firebase DB
     console.log("Remove succeeded.")
   })
   .catch(function(error) {
     console.log("Remove failed: " + error.message)
   });

  });
// keeping this separate so that even if the item is removed by any other means (e.g.- directly from server console) this UI will remain in sync
rootRef.on('child_removed', function(snap) {
  var key = snap.key;
  $('#'+key).remove();
});
```

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with firebase. StackOverflow is not a forum where people will help you through large problems. Break your problem down into multiple questions and ask each one separately.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the [.on](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) method to attach your handler, to have triggered by the help of 'document' and only if the button exists?

```
$(document).on('click', ".removeEmployee", function(){
  alert('My text : ' + $(this).text());
});
```

*(Btw, you are trying to select button with a '#' which is used for selecting by element id. But removeEmployee is a css class so you need to use '.removeEmployee')*

Here is a demonstration for the handler created before the element :

```js
console.log("Attaching handler");
setTimeout(function() {
  $(document).on('click', ".removeEmployee", function() {
    alert('My text : ' + $(this).text());
  });
  console.log("Creating the button");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#container').append('<button class="removeEmployee">Remove</button>');
    console.log("Ready for click!")
  }, 1000);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue has nothing to do with firebase.

JQuery doesn't automatically hook up click events for dynamically created content; You have to add those click handlers manually. This is best done when you create the new elements.

```
// wrap in a jquery object
var btn = $("<button key='"+ key +"' class='removeEmployee mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent'>Remove</button>");

// then add a click event handler to it
btn.on('click', function() {
    var key = $(this).attr('key');
    alert("clicked! " + key);
});

// then add it to the table
$("#table_body").append("<tr id='"+key+"'><td>" + id + "</td><td>" + name + "</td> <td>" + email + "</td><td><button>" + btn +"</button></td></tr>");
```